# lock deletion issue when uploading information to Sonar server on AIX

Tags: sonarqube, aix, sonarqube-scan

I'm actually trying to use sonarqube 5.4 on an AIX server and I've got some errors when running the analysis.

the same configuration has been tested on Windows and it's working.

The information are stored in an Oracle database(11gr2)

At the end of the analysis, it says that a lock file can't be deleted, but when I check after this file, it's not there anymore.

I've tried to use the last version of the wrapper, but in vain.

has anyone faced the same issue?

---

> 09:58:13.581 DEBUG - POST 500
>   http:/foobar:9001/api/ce/submit?projectKey=IHM&projectName=IHM
>   | time=92ms 09:58:13.594 INFO  - Analysis report generated in
>   /applis/swgi/produits/ictools/workdir/batch-report 09:58:13.604 DEBUG
>   - Couldn't delete lock file: /applis/swgi/produits/ictools/sonar-runner-2.4_IHM/bin/./.sonar_lock
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   /applis/swgi/produits/ictools/sonar-runner-2.4_IHM/bin/./.sonar_lock
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:98)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:114)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:119)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:256)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:115)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1137)  at
>   org.sonar.home.cache.DirectoryLock.unlock(DirectoryLock.java:98)

---

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:594)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>           at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>           at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
>           at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>           at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>           at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 http:/foobar:9001/api/ce/submit?projectKey=IHM&projectName=IHM
>           at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:32)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:96)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:67)
>           at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:158)
>           at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:117)
>           at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(PhaseExecutor.java:129)
>           at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:112)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:259)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:249)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.startComponents(ProjectScanContainer.java:127)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
>           at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
>           at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
>           at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
>           ... 9 more

Comment: Perhaps it couldn't even _create_ the lock-file, just didn't check it. The directory `/applis/swgi/produits/ictools/sonar-runner-2.4_IHM/bin/` should be writeable. (It does sound lame though... lock-file in the `bin` directory?!)

Comment: Hello, I've tried creating the file mentionned here with the same user, and it was a success (fortunately or unfortunately :) )

Comment: and indeed for the folders, as I'm still in testing, I've let all the default folders, plenty of time to make it clean and fancy after :)

Comment: before running it, try this: `touch /applis/swgi/produits/ictools/sonar-runner-2.4_IHM/bin/.sonar_lock`

Comment: the touch is w:orking fine, the user can write in this folder : swgiadm@dswg01:/applis/swgi/swgiadm # touch /applis/swgi/produits/ictools/sonar-runner-2.4_IHM/bin/.sona..r_lock
swgiadm@dswg01:/applis/swgi/swgiadm